# Compilation boost c++ code errors

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

Here is the code (from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/container/move_emplace.html)

```
#include <boost/container/list.hpp>
#include <cassert>
class non_copy_movable
{
   non_copy_movable(const non_copy_movable &);
   non_copy_movable& operator=(const non_copy_movable &);

   public:
   non_copy_movable(int = 0) {}
};
int main ()
{
   using namespace boost::container;
   list<non_copy_movable> l;
   non_copy_movable ncm;
   l.emplace(l.begin(), 0);
   assert(l.size() == 1);
   l.emplace(l.begin());
   assert(l.size() == 2);
   return 0;
}
```

I have problem with compilation. I have tried:

```
g++ 2.cpp -o 2 -I /usr/include/boost
```

and also other combination but it is wrong.

Errors:

```
2.cpp:1:36: error: boost/container/list.hpp: No such file or directory
2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
2.cpp:13: error: ‘boost’ has not been declared
2.cpp:13: error: ‘container’ is not a namespace-name
2.cpp:13: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
2.cpp:14: error: ‘list’ was not declared in this scope
2.cpp:14: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
2.cpp:14: error: ‘l’ was not declared in this scope
```

I have "boost include" in path:
/usr/include/boost
in /usr/lib there is nothing connected with boost.
I have installed boost on ubuntu using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Have you got some universal compilation for boost program?
Another program with is also written in c++ using boost I compile normally without errors:

```
g++ 1.cpp -o 1
./1
```

Comment: :/usr/include/boost/container$ dpkg -S list.hpp said
libboost1.48-dev: /usr/include/boost/container/list.hpp

Answer (score 0):

Most of boost are header-only libraries so I'm not surprised that you don't see many, if any boost libraries in /usr/lib.

That said, I think your include path setting is wrong. You're trying to include boost/container/list.hpp but your include path already has "boost" in it. Unless the libraries are installing /usr/include/boost/boost, you either need to remove "boost" from the include path or from the #include line. My preference would be to remove it from the include path as a statement like `#include <boost/container/list.hpp>` is a lot more informative than `#include <container/list.hpp>`.

Comment: Your code compiled w/o errors for me; using both clang and gcc 4.2.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have still the same errors. I have tried to remove boost from header or line compilation.
#include <container/list.hpp>
or
g++ 2.cpp -o 2 -I /usr/include. 
I have tried also other combinations.

Comment: Have you verified if the boost includes are actually in /usr/include?

Comment: I have checked in command line cd /usr/include/boost
there are some file mostly *.hpp. There is not a "container" directory but e.g. "algorithm" director is exists (there are e.g. minmax.hpp).

Comment: Well there's your problem. Try re-installing the library or something? Is there anything in /usr/local/include?

Comment: Ok, in /usr/local/include there is nothing.
In /usr/include/boost/assign/std there is list.hpp. I changed:
#include <boost/assign/std/list.hpp>. I am trying to solve the problem because I have still errors, e.g. error: ‘container’ is not a namespace-name. The code is from official webside.

Comment: boost/assign/std/list.hpp and boost/container/list.hpp are very different files that implement very different pieces of functionality. It sounds to me like your boost installation isn't complete. I just looked into my boost (complete) 1.52 install here and you should have the files in the place that you originally tried to pull them from.